# What is the better way to generate data in R instead of a for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation, parallel.foreach

I am a brand new R user, trying to generate a large amount of data with specified dependent associations into a single data.frame.

My current code uses a for-loop and works fine (N=250 ids, over 10 replications), but I will have to expand it into a larger N and larger K replications.  I have tried parallel processing using foreach and functions without much success. I cannot get the replicated data to add to the final frame.

Any help or direction will be much appreciated.

Current code:

```
set.seed(0)

Kreps <- 10  

id= as.numeric(1:250)

sim=do.call("rbind", replicate(Kreps,data.frame(id), simplify=FALSE))

sim$Krep_num = as.numeric(gl(Kreps,250))
obs1<-nrow(sim)

for(m in 1:Kreps  ){ 
  sim$z1= rbinom(obs1, 1, 0.35)

  sim$x1= rbinom(obs1, 1,exp(log(0.10)+ (log(1.15)*sim$z1)))
                   
  sim$y=  rbinom(obs1, 1,exp(log(0.025)+(log(2)*sim$x1) + (log(1.2)*sim$z1)) )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing about speeding up simulations in R is similar to **vectorization** of any piece of code in R. Basically whenever possible use internal functions rather than `for-loops`. Sometimes a mathematical relation can be derived and several calls can be removed from the pipe. In this case simply removing the for loop, and performing all the simulations in 3 calls to `rbinom` will speed it up plenty.

```
set.seed(0)
Kreps <- 10  
id = 1:250
obs1 <- Kreps * length(id)
nsim <- obs1 * Kreps
df <- data.frame(id = rep(id, kreps))
df$z1 <- rbinom(nsim, 1, 0.35)
df$x1 <- rbinom(nsim, 1, exp(log(.1) + log(1.15) * df$z1))
df$y <- rbinom(nsim, 1, exp(log(.025) + log(2) * df$z1+ log(1.2) * df$x1))
```

Also when you want to replicate your data, `rep` will be much faster than `replicate`. `rep` simply copies your dataset, while `replicate` replicates the **call** that you place. Eg. `rep(rbinom(1e6), 10)` is (roughly) equivalent to `x <- rbinom(1e6); unlist(lapply(1:6, function(z)x))`, while `replicate(10, rbinom(1e6))` is roughly equivalent to `lapply(1:6, function(x)rbinom(1e6))`.